# how to install python packages upon creation of instance on GCP

Tags: python, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I want to install several private python packages when I create an instance (AI platform).

I had the following startup script but it did not install what I needed (but also didnt show any errors):

startup_script.sh:

`pip install my_custom_libraries`

why does it not work and what do I need to do to make it work?

Comment: Where are stored the private python package? Do you need credential to access them?

Answer (score 2):

you check the start up script logs at :

```
Compute Engine > (Your Instance Name) > Logs > Serial port 1 (console)
```

also, I am not sure your install have by default python and pip installed ?

startup_script.sh:

```
#! /bin/bash
apt-get update
apt-get install -yq git python python-pip
pip install --upgrade pip virtualenv
pip install my_custom_libraries
```

check your python and pip set at the proper path